# How to transform a collection into a custom key/value array with nested arrays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to return my collection into an array that Chatfuel, and specifically Messenger, understands. When calling `User::get()`, I get a collection of all the users, but I need to map it out to the [JSON array that Chatfuel expects](https://docs.chatfuel.com/api/json-api/json-api).

I've previously (when I was using raw PHP and no framework), done it like so:

```
<?php
$det = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $row_array['title'] = $row['book-title'] . " | " . $row['edition'] . " Edition";
        $row_array['image_url'] = $row['image-url'];
        $row_array['subtitle'] = $row['author'];
        if (!empty($_SESSION['loggedinuniid'])) {
            $urllink = "https://example.com/textbook/?isbn=" . $row['isbn'] . '&uni=' . $_SESSION['loggedinuniid'] . '&submit';
        } else {
            $urllink = "https://example.com/textbook/?isbn=" . $row['isbn'] . '&submit';
        }
        $row_array['item_url'] = $urllink;
        if ($row['rrs'] == 0) {
            $row_array['buttons'] = array(array('type' => 'web_url', 'url' => $urllink, 'title' => 'See Textbook'));
        } else {
            $row_array['buttons'] = array(array('type' => 'web_url', 'url' => $urllink . '#selling', 'title' => 'Buy Textbook (' . $row['rrs'] . ')'));
        }
        array_push($det, $row_array);
    }
    $row_array['title'] = "Find Textbooks on example";
    $row_array['subtitle'] = "Search for textbooks sold by your classmates at uni!";
    $row_array['image_url'] = "";
    $urllink = "https://example.com/";
    $row_array['item_url'] = $urllink;
    $row_array['buttons'] = array(array('type' => 'web_url', 'url' => $urllink, 'title' => 'See All Textbooks'));
    array_push($det, $row_array);
    $final = array(
        'messages' => array(
            array("attachment" => array(
                "type" => "template", "payload" => array(
                    "template_type" => "generic", "elements" => $det,
                ),
            ),
            ),
            array("text" => "Hope this helps! You can also always search on example.com!"),
        ),
    );
    $post_data = json_encode($final);
    exit($post_data);
```

And, while it got the job done, it isn't really readable or clean.

What's the best way to take an existing collection, and map it out to a custom key/value array I need?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the word `COLLECTION`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections - as far as I understand Eloquent automatically returns a collection; an array on steroids.

Comment: This is probably too broad, but get your Collection, then loop it: `$results = User::get();`, then `foreach($results as $row)`, which would be almost the same as `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))`, and instead of `$row["whatever"]`, use `$row->whatever`, then just perform the same operations as above.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of just doing that, but honestly I was hoping to avoid the whole mishmash as above. It seems in Javascript this is easier :P

Comment: Understandable, but I don't think that's avoidable. How would you do this in JS? Could that logic be mimicked in PHP?

Comment: I might've spoken to soon, it was based on [this](https://adamwathan.me/2016/07/14/customizing-keys-when-mapping-collections/) but it seems to completely forgo the array keys... besides, I'm working with nested arrays too... I'll use this for now but I can't believe it takes 40 lines of code to transform an array :P